# Nature of the improper integral $\int_1^∞ \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2\sqrt{\log x}}\text{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

**Problem:** $$\int_1^∞ \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2\sqrt{\log x}}\text dx$$

**My try:** in order to take care of $\sqrt{\log x}$, I went on to substitute $$x=e^{t^2}$$ which gives

$$\int_0^∞ \frac{e^{2t^2}}{(1+e^{2t^2})^2.t}2t.e^{t^2}\text{d}t$$, $t$ cancels out

$$= 2\int_0^∞ \frac{e^{3t^2}}{(1+e^{2t^2})^2}\text{d}t$$,
 after which I took $e^{t^2}$ out from bracket

$$=2\int_0^∞ \frac{e^{t^2}}{(e^{-t^2}+e^{t^2})^2}\text{d}t$$

Can someone hint what next or some other way 
completely different than this one.

Also, can we say that this integral has the same nature if we exchange $t^2$ with $t$ and find it's nature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the integral

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2\sqrt{\log{x}}}dx$$

Let us define $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2\sqrt{\log{x}}}$

We see that the only suspicious points are $1$ and $\infty$, since the integrand is bounded in a neighborhood of every other point in $[1,\infty)$.

the integral is convergent at 1, as we see from the comparison test with $g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log{x}}}$:

$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}\to{}\frac{1}{4}$ as $x\to{}1$, and $\int_{1}^{2}g(x)dx$ converges (why?)

The integral is convergent at infinity, as we see from the comparison test with $h(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$:

$\frac{f(x)}{h(x)}=\frac{x^4}{(1+x^2)^2\sqrt{\log{x}}}\to{}0$ as $x\to{}\infty$, and $\int_{1}^{\infty}h(x)dx$ converges.

Thus, the integral is absolutely convergent.

Exchanging $t$ and $t^2$ does not preserve the nature of the integral in general; consider
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t^2}dt$$
and
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t}dt$$